# How to hide navigational bars according to cursor positions to use full screen?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am trying to hide the navigational bars according to the cursor positions.so, that I can use the full screen of the iPhone. But I donno how to start it.

Similar (less confusing :) ) question: [Show/hide UIToolbar, "match finger movement", precisely as in for example iOS7 Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21929220/show-hide-uitoolbar-match-finger-movement-precisely-as-in-for-example-ios7-s)

Comment: Where the hell is the mouse here? You are working for iPhone and not for machine.

Comment: like cursor moving on to the navigation bar it should shown and when the cursor is moved on to the screen the navigation bar should be invisible

Comment: theres no cursor in iPhone dude... I think you might be having some problem in understanding iPhone

Comment: i may be worng but i know iPhone.consider it as touch event

Comment: touch event can be anywhere. and nobody is gonna move his finger on iphone like we have to move cursor. So what i suggest is you jus put button clicking on which will hide unhide your navigationbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code if you want to hide and unhide the navigation bar on double tap on any part of the view

In your .h file:

```
IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

Connect the IBOutlet in your XIB.

in your .m file:

```
  -(void)viewDidLoad {

  [super viewDidLoad];

  [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];



 }

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{ UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

  if (touch.tapCount == 2) {

       [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
       [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0) target:self   selector:@selector(hideBar) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];


      }

  }

-(void)hidebar{

[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];



}
```

Do the modifications as per your requirement.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

There is no cursor on iPhone, but do you mean that you want to do something like safari - hide the address bar when scroll down more than one screen page?

Assume that you are using UITableView, I have a solution that:
1. we are already know height of each table row -> cell.frame.size.heigh
2. and we already know height of screen -> view.bounds.size.height
3. UITableView call cellForRowAtIndexPath every time it generate a cell
So you can easily know how many cells are there in you table, row index and total height of them, whenever you see a row index which belong to next screen page, you should hide navigation bar with an animation. otherwise, if all row index are belong to 1st screen -> show navigation bar with animation.